# Not able to upload image to remote server

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, ionic-framework

I am pretty new to ionic framework and all I am trying to do is create a form where the user can take an image and add information about the image and submit it. The image needs to be submitted along with form.

The `php` part is ready and I have tested that using postman, the form accepts the information you see in following screenshot.

Note: `gift_image` is a `file` that gets submitted.

Once I submit the form all works well.

[image]

When I try the same thing in ionic other than the `gift_image` part everything else gets saved perfectly fine.

I managed to get the complete path of the image in ionic and lets say it is

`file:///data/user/0/com.abc.xyz/files/PFflg1477417776371.jpg`

While submitting the form i make the image part of the `json` that gets sent to the server

```
{"name":"some dummy name","supplier":"","colour":"","size":"","details":"dummy details","price":"","gift_image":{"fileKey":"file","fileName":"file:\/\/\/data\/user\/0\/com.abc.xyz\/files\/PFflg1477417776371.jpg","mimeType":"image\/jpeg","chunkedMode":true}}
```

The problem I face is `gift_image` is not being sent as a `$_FILE` I only see this in `$_POST`

How can i correct this issue? I have spent over 2 days trying to resolve this and I am pretty much out of all ideas.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What code are you using to send the file? Also, are you sure you're actually sending the file, and not just the filepath?

Comment: the entire form data is saved in `$scope.gift` which looks like the `json` i shared in question. That gets sent over to an api in a post request. Regarding second part of the question I am confused about that my self as I am not sure if only the file details are being sent or the file is also going, how do i check that?

Comment: Well first of all, files cannot be POSTed in the same way as json or other text data (by default). It will need to have content type `Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=[boundary text here]`, and the payload will have multiple parts separated by `[boundary text here]`.

Comment: The fact that you're sending it as json makes it probable that you're just sending it as json text. In reality, you will need to use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) API or some library that uses it to send a file.

Comment: suppose i use `FormData` to achieve this, how do I then make that part of the `$scope` variable that gets submitted to the api

Comment: The `$scope.formData = new FormData();` then modify the object.

Comment: I need a bit more help understanding that, can we chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126657/discussion-between-baig-and-tcooc).